# How and why do we have to find $\frac{du}{dx}$ in order to solve the Euler-Cauchy equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> **Question:**
>
> Use variation of parameters to find a particular solution to the
>   inhomogeneous Euler-Cauchy equation,
>
> $$x^2\frac{d^2y(x)}{dx^2}-12x\frac{dy(x)}{dx}+42y(x)=-\frac{32}{x}$$
>
> **What is the expression for $\frac{d u(x)}{dx}$?**

$$\color{crimson}{----------------------------------------}$$

$$\Large{\color{crimson}{\text{My Struggle:}}}$$

What is the expression for $\frac{d u(x)}{dx}$? What am I supposed to do here, and why is it useful? Because I never use such a thing to solve these problems (See my way of solving below).

$$\color{crimson}{----------------------------------------}$$

**My way of solving:**

The way I was taught was to use subsituition $y=x^m$, and go as follows:

$$y=x^m$$
$$y'=mx^{m-1}$$
$$y''=m(m-1)x^{m-2}$$

Homogeneous form:
$$x^2[m(m-1)x^{m-2}]-12x[mx^{m-1}]+42x^m=0$$

$$m(m-1)x^m-12mx^m+42x^m=0$$

$$x^m[m(m-1)-12m+42]=0$$

$$x^m[m^2-13m+42]=0$$

Auxiliary Equation:

$$m^2-13m+42=0$$

$$m=7,6$$

$$y_h=Ax^7+Bx^6$$

$$\color{red}{\text{and so on....}}$$

As you can see, I perform a substitution of y on x, and do not create a new variable $u$?

Comment: What is $u(x)$?

Comment: @CheeHan A function in terms on x.

Comment: What I meant by my question: is there any relationship between $u$ and $y$?

Comment: @CheeHan They haven't given anything like that in the question. But obviously there is, because u depends on x and y depends on x.

Comment: Unless that information is given, nobody can solve for $\frac{d}{dx}(u(x))$. Maybe your lecturer/textbook state it somewhere? Also, the question asks for variation of parameters method, but you did it by substituting an ansatz. [My bad, ignore my last sentence, you did the right thing there, just haven't finished it yet]

Comment: @CheeHan That's the second part of the question, to find $u(x)$

Comment: I know, but all you obtained from part one is $y(x)$. You cannot just say find $u(x)$ without knowing the relationship between $y(x)$ and $u(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

The solution of the associated homogeneous ODE : $x^2y''-12xy'+42y=0$ is :
$$y_p=c_1x^7+c_2x^6$$
as alrerady shown by "the Artist".

To apply the method of "variation of parameter" we take any one of the preceeding solution, for example $c_2x^6$ and we replace the parameter by an unknown function $f(x)$ :

$ y=f(x)x^6 \quad\to\quad y'=x^6f'+6x^5f \quad\to\quad y''=x^6f''+12x^5f'+ 40x^4f$

$x^2(x^6f''+12x^5f'+ 30x^4f)-12x(x^6f'+6x^5)+42x^7f=-\frac{32}{x}$
$$x^8f''=-\frac{32}{x}$$
$$f'=\frac{4}{x^8}+c_1$$
$$f=-\frac{4}{7x^7}+c_1x+c_2$$
$$y(x)=-\frac{4}{7x}+c_1x^7+c_2x^6$$

I suppose that you can take it from here, because you have the COMPLETE wording of the problem which gives you the clue to relate $u(x)$ to $y(x)$.